# get a reminder when my Outlook pst file size is close to a limit

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

My pst file was corrupted oncein the past. After getting it back, a friend told me that I need to backup the pst file and pay attention to the pst file size more frequently.

I can check the file size by check the pst file in my C drive. But now I'm thinking if there is a way to get a reminder when my Outlook pst file size is close to a limit. The limit will be set by myself. Any Ideas?

Comment: Write a script and use the Windows task scheduler.

Comment: The .pst size limit in 2010 is extremely large....Do you have 50GB .PST files?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments the size of the PST for Outlook 2010 is extremely large.

According to this [site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832925/how-to-configure-the-size-limit-for-both-.pst-and-.ost-files-in-outlook) the limit is 50GB with a warning appearing at 47.5GB. The same site also suggests you can amend the registry to change the limit should you wish.

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog.
2. Type in `regedit` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>
3. **Take a backup of your registry at this point!**
4. Navigate to either of the following locations:

   If you are using a standalone installation of Office use:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\PST
   ```

   If your email is managed centrally visit:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\PST
   ```
5. Locate the key `WarnLargeFileSize`. If the key doesn't exist click Edit in the menu bar and choose New > DWORD and enter the name `WarnLargeFileSize`.
6. This entry only accepts inputs in hexadecimal and refers to megabytes so you will need to input the limit value as hex. You can use the convertor located [here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter). The default (and maximum value) for this field is `0x0000BE00` (48,640 in decimal).
7. Once added, close regedit and reopen Outlook. Your new limit should be applied.